# Why does my deep-learning model give this ValueError?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deeplearning4j

I am trying to create a deep learning model to identify person with mask or without mask but unfortunately i got this error

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:1940: UserWarning: `Model.fit_generator` is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Please use `Model.fit`, which supports generators.
  warnings.warn('`Model.fit_generator` is deprecated and '
Epoch 1/50
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-57c416e2df76> in <module>()
      2     training_set,
      3     validation_data=test_set,
----> 4     epochs=50
      5 )

10 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    984           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    985             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
--> 986               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    987             else:
    988               raise

ValueError: in user code:

    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:855 train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:845 step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:1285 run
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2833 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:3608 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:838 run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:797 train_step
        y, y_pred, sample_weight, regularization_losses=self.losses)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/compile_utils.py:204 __call__
        loss_value = loss_obj(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=sw)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/losses.py:155 __call__
        losses = call_fn(y_true, y_pred)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/losses.py:259 call  **
        return ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:206 wrapper
        return target(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/losses.py:1755 binary_crossentropy
        y_true, y_pred, from_logits=from_logits), axis=-1)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:206 wrapper
        return target(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py:5023 binary_crossentropy
        return nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=target, logits=output)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:206 wrapper
        return target(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_impl.py:133 sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits
        (logits.get_shape(), labels.get_shape()))

    ValueError: logits and labels must have the same shape ((None, 2) vs (None, 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your shapes of **'labels'** and **'logits'**, it does not match. This is common problem in model creation.

Answer (score 1):

shape of labels and output should be same because of that it gives error, `ValueError: logits and labels must have the same shape ((None, 2) vs (None, 1))`